# Versions package producing unexpected behavior

Tags: versions

I want to create a package for formatting problem sets. Also, I want an easy way to produce versions with the problem statement and the solutions and versions with only the problem statements. I have something almost like what I want (see below). The only thing going wrong is that I don't get the "Begin Solution ... End Solution" when I include the solutions (I do get the "solution text goes here"). Note that I want the problem environment to change based on whether the solutions are included or not, which is why I had my own `\IncludeSolutions` command wrapped around the `\includeversion` command. Any suggestions on how to make this work? I'm also not particularly attached to this approach, so let me know if there is a superior way of approaching the problem. I myself thought of a better way to do this would be to use `kvoptions` to pass an argument to my package, and then define my problem/solution environments based on the argument, rather than using a separate command to redefine the problem environment, but I couldn't get this to work, either.

I define the commands in MyProblemSet as follows.

```
\ProvidesPackage{MyProblemSet}

\RequirePackage{versions}

\newenvironment{problem}
{
    \textbf{Begin Problem (without solution)}:\\
}
{
    \\\textbf{End Problem (without solution)}\\
}

\newenvironment{solution}
{
    \textbf{Begin Solution}:\\
}
{
    \\\textbf{End Solution}\\
}
\excludeversion{solution}

\newcommand{\IncludeSolutions}
{
    \renewenvironment{problem}
    {
        \textbf{Begin Problem (with solution)}:\\
    }
    {
        \\\textbf{End Problem (with solution)}\\
    }
    \includeversion{solution}
}
```

Here is an example of how I would like to use them.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{MyProblemSet}
    \IncludeSolutions

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
problem text goes here
\end{problem}
\begin{solution}
solution text goes here
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Here's an idea.  `\usepackage{etoolbox}` to create 
`\newtoggle{includesolutions}`. Create your `solution` environment with `\NewEnviron` from `\usepackage{environ}` and put the toggle around your text and the `\BODY`.

Comment: There are a few packages that do this kind of thing- the `answers` is my favourite. Of course, that's not to say that you shouldn't create your own.... One thing to be careful of- you need to use `%` in some of your environment definitions to avoid extra vertical space

Comment: You could also borrow some code from the [`exam`](http://ctan.org/pkg/exam) package/class.  The `\[no]printanswers` macro does what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies: I had been using the `exam` package, but I wanted more control than I thought I could get without writing my own package (this wasn't reflected in my minimal working example). Anyway, I tried using `kvoptions.sty` again, and got it to work this time (I'm not sure what I messed up before). Here is what I did.

This is my `testkv.sty` file

```
\ProvidesPackage{testkv}

\RequirePackage{verbatim}
\RequirePackage{kvoptions}
\SetupKeyvalOptions
{
    family = TKV,
    prefix = TKV@
}

\DeclareBoolOption[false]{solutions}

\ProcessKeyvalOptions*

\ifTKV@solutions
    \newcommand{\status}{yes solutions}
    \newenvironment{solution}
    {
        \textbf{Begin Solution}\\
    }
    {
        \\\textbf{End Solution}\\
    }
    \newenvironment{problem}
    {
        \textbf{Begin Problem}\\
    }
    {
        \\\textbf{End Problem}\\
    }
\else
    \newcommand{\status}{no solutions}
    \newenvironment{solution}
    {
        \comment
    }
    {
        \endcomment
    }
    \newenvironment{problem}
    {
        \textit{Begin Problem}\\
    }
    {
        \\\textit{End Problem}\\
    }
\fi
```

and this is my main file

```
\documentclass{article}
    % \usepackage[solutions = false]{testkv}
    \usepackage[solutions = true]{testkv}

\begin{document}

\begin{problem}
problem text goes here
\end{problem}
\begin{solution}
solution text goes here
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```